# Where do I configure hapi.js coookie configuration in an electrode server?

Tags: walmart-electrode

I'm trying to get cookie info from the req object.  I see how to configure a cookie in hapi.js but how do I pass or configure a cookie in electrode-server?  Do I need to pass in a "server" configuration or a "connection" configuration in config/default.json?

Comment: I'm not sure if the electrode team follows their tag on SO. They have a chatroom where they might help you if no-one posts an answer here (but please circle back and post the answer here from the chatroom): https://gitter.im/electrode-io/electrode

Answer (score 0):

electrode-server is just a bootstrap layer.  Once Hapi server is up and running, electrode-server is pretty much out of the picture.

You get back the Hapi server instance after electrode server returns:

```
electrodeServer(config).then( server => { } )
```

In your Hapi route handlers and lifecycle events, you get the request and reply objects, which are the original Hapi objects and all Hapi APIs related to cookies are there.

For example, in your route handler:

```
function handler(request, reply) {
    reply('Hello').state('data', { firstVisit: false }); // set a cookie
}
```